# SQL Renaming NULL with string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, null

I have looked through questions here and have not been able to find exactly what I am looking for.

How would I create a query in mysql that would return missing data in field Name in database Demo as a string (such as 'Blank') instead of NULL?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: `COALESCE(Column, 'Blank')`

Comment: I am still having some difficulty. When I SELECT fieldname1, IFNULL(fieldname2, 'Blank')FROM Table1, I do not get results.

Comment: Then the table is empty.

Comment: I apologize. I mean I get '0' instead of 'Blank' for NULL.

Comment: If the datatype of the column is something numeric you would need to cast that to string inside the coalesce. But best to just do this in your presentation layer anyway.

Comment: It is not numeric data. It is frustrating to stumble on something so simple. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: It also is only returning rows with the null data. What I am hoping to achieve is to retrieve all data and have the 'NULL' replaced with the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT IFNULL(fieldname, 'Blank') FROM tablename
```

or

```
SELECT COALESCE(fieldname, 'Blank') FROM tablename
```

Comment: So, what worked for me was SELECT IF (fieldname IS NULL, 'Blank', fieldname) AS fieldname FROM Table. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And I ultimately was able to get the options above to work for me. I'm still not sure what I was doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in MySQL you can use `IFNULL`, as in:

```
SELECT IFNULL(fieldname, 'Blank') as fieldname, ...
```

Comment: Null results are now showing up as 0 instead of as 'Blank'

Answer (score -2):

I'm not really sure what you're aiming at, but maybe you look for something like this?

```
SELECT IF(ISNULL(a.yourfield),'Blank', a.yourfield)
FROM yourtable A;
```

[`ISNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) returns 1 if the argument is `NULL`, otherwise it returns 0.

Comment: She's trying to return the string "Blank" if the field is NULL.

Comment: Far too convoluted compared to the other answers.

Comment: @PaulG, How do you know it's she/he? :)

Comment: @Rahul Anna is a feminine name AFAIK?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, got it ... LOL

Comment: I would be sad if I were a dude named Anna. I am getting '0' returned for null instead of 'Blank' when I SELECT field1, field2 AND coalesce(field2, 'BLANK')
FROM Table

Comment: So, what worked for me was SELECT IF (fieldname IS NULL, 'Blank', fieldname) AS fieldname FROM Table. Thanks for your help!